# How loop edge set the arrow type?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

When we use `->` tha arrow type can be overwritten by `>=Arrow`, before or after the `->` . Or by putting after the `->` another `-Arrow` style.

For a `loop` edge, we can overwrite the arrow type by `>=Arrow` but not by `-Arrow`. **Why ?**

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=5, very thick]
    \draw[green]                (0,0) edge[loop, -latex] ();  % ->
    \draw[xshift=3mm]           (0,0) edge[loop, >=latex] (); % -latex
    \draw[green, scale=-1]      (0,0) edge[-latex, loop] ();  % ->
    \draw[xshift=3mm,scale=-1]  (0,0) edge[>=latex, loop] (); % -latex

    \draw[yshift=3mm,blue]      (0,0) edge[>=latex, ->, -Ellipse] (.3,0); % -Ellipse
    \draw[yshift=-3mm,red]      (0,0) edge[>=latex, -Ellipse, ->] (.3,0); % -latex
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer. Looking in the code we find :

> ```
> \tikzstyle{loop}=                    [to path={
>   \pgfextra{\let\tikztotarget=\tikztostart}
>   [looseness=8,min distance=5mm,every loop]
>   \tikz@to@curve@path
>   }]
> ```
>
> ```
> \tikzstyle{every loop}=              [->,shorten >=1pt]
> ```

So the style `every loop` is invoked in `to path`. In this way when we use `edge[loop, -latex]` this is style "equivalent"  to `edge[loop, -latex][every loop]`.

**So we have the unusual position of `every loop` after the custom style.**

For this reason if we put `edge[loop, shorten >=5pt]` will not work. We have to say `every loop/.style={->,shorten >=5pt}`.